# Passing Values to RIGHT() using LEN()

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that contains a [Work Phone] (nvarchar) column. The software that used this database allowed users to enter any characters so a lot of the columns contained things like "**555-555-5555 Ext. 1234 Bob Jones**". The only thing I need are the digits and I intend to split the Phone and Ext into seperate columns. After running a function and a few other things I'm down to just the phone and extension numbers. All spaces and letters have been removed (e.g. 55555555551234).

The way I'm trying to split this, I'm first going to grab the extension by counting the total number of characters in the field (in my example case **14**) and then reducing that number by 10 (the total number of characters in a phone number (excluding country codes)). Because the extensions could be anywhere between 1-5 characters I'm trying to use LEN() to get this count and then reducing it by 10.

```
SELECT RIGHT([Table].[Column], LEN([Table].[Column]) -10)
FROM [Table]
```

What I get is "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function."

I don't entirely understand the problem because if I just do something like:

```
SELECT LEN([Table].[Column]) -10
SELECT LEN('55555555551234') -10
```

I get the value 4 as expected.

What's the proper way to pass this parameter to RIGHT so I can get what I want (or is there just an entirely better way to do this)?

Comment: The error message you are getting occurs when then the LEN([Table].[Column]) -10 passed to the RIGHT function evaluates to a negative number. This would occur if the column has a length of 9 or less in this example.



(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All items in the table are greater than or equal to 10?

```
SELECT RIGHT(55555555551234, LEN(55555555551234) -10)
SELECT RIGHT(5555555555, LEN(5555555555) -10)
SELECT RIGHT(55555555, LEN(55555555) -10)
```

Try

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN LEN([Table].[Column)]) > 10
   THEN RIGHT([Table].[Column], LEN([Table].[Column]) - 10)
   END
   FROM    [Table]
```

Comment: Add an `ELSE` to the `CASE` (like David Welker's answer does), or the result will be NULL, when LEN <= 10.

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because subtracting 10 sometimes brings back a negative. You will want to put a case statement around it.

IE.

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT([TABLE].[Column], 
    CASE when LEN([TABLE].[Column])-10 >= 0 then 
        LEN([TABLE].     [Column])-10 
    ELSE LEN([TABLE].[Column]) 
    END) 
FROM [TABLE]
```

Of course, there are other ways you can use the CASE, this is only an example to show you where it is erroring ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the string pattern, you can use PARSENAME to break it out

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(100) = '555-555-5555 Ext. 1234 Bob Jones';
SELECT @foo = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@foo, 'Ext.', ' '), '  ', ''), ' ', '.');
SELECT
    @foo,
    PARSENAME(@foo, 1),
    PARSENAME(@foo, 2),
    PARSENAME(@foo, 3),
    PARSENAME(@foo, 4)
```

This depends on how the name part is constructed

Answer (score 0):

You can try the STUFF function to get the extension:

```
SELECT STUFF('55555555551234',1,10,'')
```

It works for shorter strings too.